# Colors mysteriously shuffled in the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

With the following `ggplot2` code in R:

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c(0, 1, 1.58,2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17, 4.58, 5.58, 6.17, 6.5, 7.0),4), y = c(0.15,0.17,0.07,0.17,0.01,0.15,0.18,0.04,-0.06,-0.08,0,0.03,-0.27,-0.93,0.04,0.12,0.08,0.15,0.04,0.15,0.03,0.09,0.11,0.13,-0.11,-0.32,-0.7,-0.78,0.07,0.04,0.06,0.12,-0.15,0.05,-0.08,0.14,-0.02,-0.14,-0.24,-0.32,-0.78,-0.81,-0.04,-0.25,-0.09,0.02,-0.13,-0.2,-0.04,0,0.02,-0.05,-0.19,-0.37,-0.57,-0.81))
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + 
   stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, size = 1, se = FALSE, aes(color = "black")) + 
   stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), size = 1, se = FALSE, aes(color = "green")) + 
   stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 3), size = 1, se = FALSE, aes(color = "orange")) + 
   stat_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x), size = 1, se = FALSE, aes(color = "blue")) +
   theme(legend.justification=c(1,1),legend.position=c(0.45,0.45),legend.title=element_blank()) +
   scale_color_manual(values=c("black","green","orange","blue"), labels=c("linear","quadratic","cubic","smooth"))
```

[image]
the legend is fine; but for some reason, three of the four curves are not colored as intended: the orange curve should be green, the blue curve should be orange, and the green curve should be blue. What am I missing?

Comment: Pass a named vector for the colors to get the order right (like `values = c("black" = "black", ...)` or go try `scale_color_identity()` with `guide = "legend"` (since the identity scales default to no guide).  I have an example of this in a blog post [here](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/07/19/manual-legends-ggplot2/#using-scale_color_identity-to-recognize-color-strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings you use in the aesthetic call are arbitrary (even though you have called them after colours). They will be converted into a factor column internally in ggplot, and the levels of the factor are determined alphabetically. The factor levels are mapped across to the vector of values in the `scale_color_manual` call *in the order they are put*.

So you can just use "a" through "d" as arbitrary strings for the color aesthetic to keep track of them and control their ordering:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
   stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, 
               size = 1, se = FALSE, aes(color = "a")) + 
   stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), 
               size = 1, se = FALSE, aes(color = "b")) + 
   stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 3), 
               size = 1, se = FALSE, aes(color = "c")) + 
   stat_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x), 
               size = 1, se = FALSE, aes(color = "d")) +
   theme(legend.justification = c(1, 1),
         legend.position      = c(0.45, 0.45),
         legend.title         = element_blank()) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "green", "orange", "blue"),
                      labels = c("linear", "quadratic", "cubic", "smooth"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the online help (my emphasis):

values
a set of aesthetic values to map data values to. The values will be matched *in order (usually alphabetical)* with the limits of the scale, or with breaks if provided. If this is a named vector, then the values will be matched based on the names instead. Data values that don't match will be given na.value.

So try

```
values=c("linear"="black","quadratic"="green","cubic"="orange","smooth"="blue")
```

or something similar.  I can't check my code as you haven't provided your input data.